# Echo adds <br> by default, what would be the cause?

Tags: php, jquery

**jquery**

```
$('registration').click(function() {
       $.post('check_code.php',
        {lemail:$('input#pro_id').val(),ccode:$('input#ccode').val()},function(result){
        alert(result+"hello");
    });     
});
```

**check_code.php**

```
 <?php session_start();

 include("configure.php");

$email =  $_POST['lemail'];
$ccode  =  $_POST['ccode'];

 echo $email; ?>
```

The php file echoes with a new line I guess `<br />` tag, when I alert I get this as output:

```
 someemail@example.com
   // why does i get this break line
 hello
```

I don't want a break line, what would be the cause? I have been checking for the bug but unable to figure it out.

Comment: are they wrapped in any tags? can you inspect the post to see if there are line breaks?

Comment: There is likely a line break after the `?>`. You could remove it completely

Comment: @Pekka웃 what do you really mean. I did not get it

Comment: do you actually see a `<br />` in the HTML source?

Comment: There is no  `<br>` in play here, the `alert()` dialog listens shows "normal" line breaks as if you would hit enter somewhere

Comment: @Pekka웃 i did not hit enter but how do i solve it?

Comment: @DavidNguyen yes they are wrapped inside a div tag

Comment: div are block elements! see my edited answer below

Comment: Are you 100% sure there is no line break in your PHP file after the `?>`?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks, yes it was the line break problem and I fixed it. Now it works perfectly. If you could answer it I would accept it as an answer and Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is a "normal" line break as if you would hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, not a `<br>` tag.

Make sure there are no hidden line breaks after the closing `?>`.

To avoid this happening, you can remove the `?>` altogether. PHP doesn't require it at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

change your php like this:

```
 <?php 
session_start();
include("configure.php");

$email =  $_POST['lemail'];
$ccode  =  $_POST['ccode'];
$email =  str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $email );

 echo $email; 
?>
```

and just in case your jquery like this:

```
$('registration').click(function() {
       $.post('check_code.php',
        {lemail:$('input#pro_id').val(),ccode:$('input#ccode').val()},function(result){
        alert($.trim(result+"hello"););
    });     
});
```

Comment: I want to know the cause i dont want to trim anyways thanks for the solution

Comment: well with the code you provided it shouldn't add any extra line, maybe add the remainder of the code so we can furthery analyze

Answer (score 0):

check `#ccode` and `#proid` css values, and see if they are `display: block;`. Change them to `display: inline;`

**edit:**

Also check to see if the texts are not in separate block elements. Like the `<div>` element that you mention in the comments. Change `<div>` in `<span>` for example.